# AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'toimage' 2

Tags: python, scipy

This is my code:

```py
for i, img in enumerate(images):
    # Write the image to a string
    try:
        s = StringIO()
    except:
        s = BytesIO()
    scipy.misc.toimage(img).save(s, format="png")
```

This is the error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tkdgu/OneDrive/바탕 화면/CycleGAN-master/CycleGAN-master/CycleGAN_train.py", line 275, in <module>
    img_logger.image_summary(tag, images, epoch + 1)
  File "C:\Users\tkdgu\OneDrive\바탕 화면\CycleGAN-master\CycleGAN-master\logger.py", line 34, in image_summary
    scipy.misc.toimage(img).save(s, format="png")
AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'toimage'
```

I can't install `scipy 1.1.0` or `1.2.0`.

I want to change `scipy.misc.toimage(img).save(s, format="png")`.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended method [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.toimage.html) is to use `PIL.Image.fromarray`

So, assuming your `images` is an iterable of numpy arrays, will save each image as a file, check [PIL.Image.save documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save) for more options

```py
from PIL import Image
for i, img in enumerate(images):
    # This will save to the disk
    Image.fromarray(img).save(f'img_{i:06d}.png', 'png')
```